# Tasker HTTP Get returns file not found

Tags: tasker

I'm attempting to use tasker to go back and forth with the ecoBee API.  In doing so, I've been unable to get past the first step due to an issue I'm running into with tasker.

Here's my setup:
Server:Port - https://api.ecobee.com:443 (I've also tried without the port, and without the https://
Path - /1/authorize
Mime Type - application/json
Trust Any Certificate

When running this i get a Tasker toast message that states  "Input/Output error for https://api.ecobee.com:443/1/authorize : java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.ecobee.com:443/1/authorize"

Going to that URL works from the phone browser and a computer browser.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: No, this has not been resolved.  I believe the issue may be related to the headers that are being passed on by tasker.

Comment: If you post this to the ecobee developers group (developer@ecobee.com), you should get an answer much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://api.ecobee.com/authorize URL instead. Seems like your URL is wrong. You can also see valid URL's for Authorize call here: [Authorization Endpoints](https://www.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/documentation/v1/auth/auth-req-resp.shtml)